# Tor Browser で、日本からのアクセスとなるよう設定することは出来ますか？

Tags: tor

Torを使用するとリクエストは複数のサーバーを経由してルーティングされるとのことですが、最終的に(自分のIPアドレスではない かつ)日本からアクセスされたように設定することは出来ますか？

[このリンク先](https://btopc.jp/etc/tor-tour-2018.html)の「4.匿名性の代償は「遅い」「Google無理」」の下に、下記選択肢が掲載されていますが

> よりプライバシーを守るために、Torbuttonはウェブページの英語版を要求することができます。
> これはあなたが母国語で読みたいウェブページを代わりに英語で表示させるかもしれません。
>
> より高いプライバシーのために、英語のウェブページを要求しますか？
> [git](https://git.schwanenlied.me/yawning/torbutton/raw/58d67d50eb41caf0493126a859646a476d6700f4/src/chrome/locale/ja/torbutton.properties)

これは(IPアドレスではなく)、単なる言語表示の設定ですか？
「はい」を押すと母国語で表示され、「いいえ」を押すと英語で表示されるだけですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor の設定ファイル `torrc` にて、`ExcludeNodes` または `ExcludeExitNodes` に接続を行わない (国の) ノードを指定することができるようです。

「日本からのアクセスのみに絞る = 日本以外のすべてを指定」になるので、設定漏れがないかを確認するのが大変そうです。

**参考:**
[Torを導入した後にやっておくこと](https://blog.cheena.net/40)

> 「ExcludeNodes」は入口・中継・出口のすべてにおいて指定したノードと接続を行いません。
> 「ExcludeExitNodes」は出口のみ指定したノードと接続を行いません。

[torrcのExcludeNodesを変更してTorの接続、ブラウジングを超高速にする方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/keiya/items/589df899ffd167f4c909)